# NSDateFormatter strange behavior

Tags: ios, json, nsdateformatter

I'm developing an iOs 4 application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I'm using a JSON web service to get some data. One of those data is a date.

To convert that date parsed by SBJson, I use the following formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

I'm using an asynchronous connection, and when it gets all data from web service I use this code to create my own objects:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* datos = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]; 

    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
    [parser release];
    [json_string release];

    NSArray* data = [datos objectForKey:kRootKey];

    cierres = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary* object = [data objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"Parser: %@, Aper: %@, Cierre: %@", [object objectForKey:kFederacionKey], [object objectForKey:kAperturaKey], [object objectForKey:kCierreKey]);
        NSString* fedName = [object objectForKey:kFederacionKey];
        NSDate* aperDate = [df dateFromString: [object objectForKey:kAperturaKey]];
        NSDate* cierreDate = [df dateFromString: [object objectForKey:kCierreKey]];

        CierreData* cierreData =
            [[CierreData alloc] initWithFederationName:fedName
                                              openDate:aperDate
                                          andCloseDate:cierreDate];
        [cierres addObject:cierreData];

        [cierreData release];
    }

    [delegate dataReceived];
}
```

This sentence `NSLog(@"Parser: %@, Aper: %@, Cierre: %@", [object objectForKey:kFederacionKey], [object objectForKey:kAperturaKey], [object objectForKey:kCierreKey]);` shows the following output on console:

**Parser: Dinamarca, Aper: 2012-01-05, Cierre: 2012-01-31**

But, `aperDate` variable is **2012-01-04 23:00:00 +0000**.

Why am I getting 2012-01-04 when it must be 2012-01-05? I have also checked JSON data on my web browser and is 2012-01-05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi may be this code will help you. try like this.

```
 NSDateFormatter *formater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a"];
        [formater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

        NSDate *now1 = [formater dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 11:07:00 PM",[[arrdate objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date"]]];

        NSLog(@"%@",now1);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a NSDate, automatically the time zone is set to GMT0, so you should set your time zone to the NSDate, for ex like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Madrid"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe it didnt work, but are you sure your problem is not related with the time zone?

Comment: I don't know what my problem is.

Comment: But, are you sure is not related with time zones? I had several problems in the past related with that. Your timestamp can be different depending on your timezone. Im onyl trying to put you in the way of the solution

Comment: Cool, just let me know how it goes and I can continue helping you